# Raspberry Pi 4 doesn't show USB camera as ttyUSB

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, raspbian, camera, port

I have an RPi camera and a USB camera connected to my RPi4.

`lsusb`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:636b Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`Bus 001 Device 004` is the USB camera with `productid:vendorid` = `0c45:636b`

`ls -l /dev/tty*` gives:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /dev/tty*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty       5,  0 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  0 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty0
crw------- 1 pi   tty       4,  1 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty1
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 10 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty10
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 11 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty11
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 12 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty12
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 13 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty13
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 14 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty14
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 15 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty15
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 16 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty16
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 17 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty17
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 18 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty18
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 19 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty19
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  2 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty2
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 20 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty20
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 21 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty21
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 22 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty22
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 23 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty23
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 24 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty24
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 25 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty25
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 26 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty26
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 27 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty27
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 28 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty28
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 29 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty29
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  3 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty3
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 30 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty30
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 31 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty31
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 32 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty32
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 33 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty33
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 34 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty34
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 35 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty35
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 36 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty36
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 37 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty37
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 38 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty38
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 39 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty39
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  4 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty4
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 40 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty40
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 41 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty41
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 42 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty42
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 43 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty43
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 44 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty44
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 45 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty45
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 46 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty46
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 47 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty47
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 48 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty48
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 49 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty49
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  5 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty5
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 50 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty50
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 51 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty51
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 52 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty52
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 53 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty53
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 54 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty54
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 55 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty55
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 56 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty56
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 57 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty57
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 58 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty58
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 59 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty59
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  6 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty6
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 60 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty60
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 61 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty61
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 62 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty62
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 63 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty63
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  7 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty7
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  8 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty8
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  9 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/tty9
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 204, 64 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/ttyAMA0
crw------- 1 root root      5,  3 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/ttyprintk
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 64 Apr 14 10:59 /dev/ttyS0
```

`dmesg` gives:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg 
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.10.103-v7l+ (dom@buildbot) (arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 8.4.0-3ubuntu1) 8.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:24:00 GMT 2022
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fd083] revision 3 (ARMv7), cr=30c5383d
[    0.000000] CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, PIPT instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
[    0.000000] random: fast init done
.
.
.
.
[    1.140673] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: host bridge /scb/pcie@7d500000 ranges:
[    1.140704] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   No bus range found for /scb/pcie@7d500000, using [bus 00-ff]
[    1.140785] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:      MEM 0x0600000000..0x063fffffff -> 0x00c0000000
[    1.140874] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   IB MEM 0x0000000000..0x00bfffffff -> 0x0400000000
[    1.196583] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: link up, 5.0 GT/s PCIe x1 (SSC)
[    1.196947] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    1.196967] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
[    1.196988] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x600000000-0x63fffffff] (bus address [0xc0000000-0xffffffff])
[    1.197078] pci 0000:00:00.0: [14e4:2711] type 01 class 0x060400
[    1.197319] pci 0000:00:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[    1.200811] PCI: bus0: Fast back to back transfers disabled
[    1.201150] pci 0000:01:00.0: [1106:3483] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    1.201276] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
[    1.201710] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[    1.205235] PCI: bus1: Fast back to back transfers disabled
[    1.205350] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 8: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    1.205375] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x600000fff 64bit]
[    1.205457] pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    1.205483] pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    1.205888] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0142)
[    1.206130] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 66
[    1.212208] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    1.213126] bcm2835-aux-uart fe215040.serial: there is not valid maps for state default
[    1.215681] iproc-rng200 fe104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    1.215998] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3ec00000 mem_size:0x40000000(1024 MiB)
[    1.216878] gpiomem-bcm2835 fe200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0xfe200000
[    1.228893] brd: module loaded
[    1.240976] loop: module loaded
[    1.242702] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    1.247659] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: GENET 5.0 EPHY: 0x0000
[    1.344647] unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: Broadcom UniMAC MDIO bus
[    1.345818] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[    1.345886] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    1.345960] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.392111] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.392147] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.395376] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: hcc params 0x002841eb hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000060000000890
[    1.396697] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.10
[    1.396717] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.396735] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.396751] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.10.103-v7l+ xhci-hcd
[    1.396768] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.397499] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.397598] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.398260] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.398287] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.398313] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    1.398811] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.10
[    1.398830] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.398847] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.398863] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.10.103-v7l+ xhci-hcd
[    1.398879] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.399590] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.399662] hub 2-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.401352] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    1.401685] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    1.401699] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    1.401714] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    1.401731] Module dwc_common_port init
[    1.402157] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    1.402278] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.402475] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.404186] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    1.407550] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.407566] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.408285] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    1.408934] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.413041] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.413385] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.413583] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.413598] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.418941] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    1.418984] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.419103] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.419569] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    1.419759] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.419790] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    1.420620] Key type ._fscrypt registered
[    1.420637] Key type .fscrypt registered
[    1.420653] Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
[    1.432283] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: there is not valid maps for state default
[    1.432580] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    1.432652] fe201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0xfe201000 (irq = 36, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    1.439048] bcm2835-aux-uart fe215040.serial: there is not valid maps for state default
[    1.439828] printk: console [ttyS0] disabled
[    1.439966] fe215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0xfe215040 (irq = 38, base_baud = 62500000) is a 16550
[    1.440166] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    1.441172] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
[    1.442225] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    1.442243] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: DMA channel allocated
[    1.471902] of_cfs_init
[    1.472160] of_cfs_init: OK
[    1.490571] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    1.492273] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.493972] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.496999] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    1.498685] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.504524] mmc0: SDHCI controller on fe340000.mmc [fe340000.mmc] using ADMA
[    1.505179] Waiting for root device PARTUUID=31d18a7c-02...
[    1.571852] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    1.614569] mmc0: new ultra high speed DDR50 SDHC card at address 0001
[    1.615418] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 SD16G 29.1 GiB
[    1.617407]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    1.645407] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    1.645492] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    1.646614] devtmpfs: mounted
[    1.656737] Freeing unused kernel memory: 2048K
[    1.694520] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.704832] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    1.704847]   with arguments:
[    1.704861]     /sbin/init
[    1.704875]     splash
[    1.704890]   with environment:
[    1.704904]     HOME=/
[    1.704918]     TERM=linux
[    1.877346] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=3431, bcdDevice= 4.21
[    1.877368] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    1.877385] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    1.879575] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.879872] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    2.186214] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    2.224545] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.301162] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.302547] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    2.382684] systemd[1]: systemd 241 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    2.383654] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
[    2.397271] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=636b, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    2.397292] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[    2.397309] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB 2.0 Camera
[    2.397326] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
[    2.397343] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: SN0001
[    2.438959] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <raspberrypi>.
[    3.201456] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.212501] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.213558] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    3.213864] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.217038] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    3.217692] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Huge Pages File System being skipped.
[    3.218936] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    3.220048] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    3.222576] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
[    3.223347] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    3.329117] i2c /dev entries driver
[    3.806286] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    3.917050] systemd-journald[125]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    4.566843] rpivid-mem feb00000.hevc-decoder: rpivid-hevcmem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb00000 length 0x00010000
[    4.567385] rpivid-mem feb10000.rpivid-local-intc: rpivid-intcmem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb10000 length 0x00001000
[    4.567924] rpivid-mem feb20000.h264-decoder: rpivid-h264mem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb20000 length 0x00010000
[    4.568452] rpivid-mem feb30000.vp9-decoder: rpivid-vp9mem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb30000 length 0x00010000
[    4.661481] vc_sm_cma: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.663697] bcm2835_vc_sm_cma_probe: Videocore shared memory driver
[    4.663724] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    4.685437] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    4.693137] [vc_sm_connected_init]: installed successfully
[    4.718077] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.727170] bcm2835_audio bcm2835_audio: card created with 4 channels
[    4.730895] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    4.733792] bcm2835_audio bcm2835_audio: card created with 4 channels
[    4.794704] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.794902] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.823645] bcm2835_codec: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.833564] bcm2835_isp: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.843154] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node output[0] registered as /dev/video13
[    4.843646] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video10
[    4.843693] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 decode
[    4.843974] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[0] registered as /dev/video14
[    4.844559] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[1] registered as /dev/video15
[    4.844989] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node stats[2] registered as /dev/video16
[    4.845018] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register output node 0 with media controller
[    4.845043] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 1 with media controller
[    4.845066] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 2 with media controller
[    4.845102] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 3 with media controller
[    4.845309] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Loaded V4L2 bcm2835-isp
[    4.849121] bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    4.851272] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video11
[    4.851334] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode
[    5.257373] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636b)
[    5.262725] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 10 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 1).
[    5.264360] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 14 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 1).
[    5.264658] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 16 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 1).
[    5.265358] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    5.281499] input: USB 2.0 Camera: CyberTrack H4  as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/input/input0
[    5.282064] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    5.282082] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    5.316536] [drm] Initialized v3d 1.0.0 20180419 for fec00000.v3d on minor 0
[    5.335551] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    5.399510] usb 1-1.2: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[    5.411247] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[    5.430621] checking generic (3e876000 384000) vs hw (0 ffffffffffffffff)
[    5.430641] fb0: switching to vc4drmfb from simple
[    5.433896] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x30
[    5.436770] vc4-drm gpu: bound fe600000.firmwarekms (ops vc4_fkms_ops [vc4])
[    5.440546] [drm] Initialized vc4 0.0.0 20140616 for gpu on minor 1
[    5.455419] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x15264345
[    5.476477] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video12
[    5.476569] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 isp
[    5.485291] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[    5.487032] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video18
[    5.487078] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 image_fx
[    5.487247] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    5.495926] bcm2835-v4l2-0: scene mode selected 0, was 0
[    5.496314] bcm2835-v4l2-0: V4L2 device registered as video2 - stills mode > 1280x720
[    5.502879] vc4-drm gpu: [drm] HDMI-A-1: EDID is invalid:
[    5.502901]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[    5.502917]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[    5.502932]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[    5.502947]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[    5.502962]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[    5.502977]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[    5.502992]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[    5.503007]  [00] ZERO 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[    5.503400] bcm2835-v4l2-0: Broadcom 2835 MMAL video capture ver 0.0.2 loaded.
[    5.515730] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x45
[    5.515787] vc4-drm gpu: [drm] fb0: vc4drmfb frame buffer device
[    5.755857] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[    5.755978] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[    5.769372] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Jan  4 2021 19:56:29 version 7.45.229 (617f1f5 CY) FWID 01-2dbd9d2e
[    7.991930] random: crng init done
[    7.991954] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[    8.014125] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[    8.184298] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[    8.804678] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
[    8.805974] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
[    9.554833] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: configuring instance for external RGMII (RX delay)
[    9.555326] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
[   12.761703] broken atomic modeset userspace detected, disabling atomic
[   15.243869] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   16.221618] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   16.221680] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   16.221687] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.221702] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.221712] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.221729] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   16.252792] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   16.252803] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   16.252866] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   16.255358] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   16.712074] fuse: init (API version 7.32)
[   16.735753] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   16.735763] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   16.735777] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   17.357545] ICMPv6: process `dhcpcd' is using deprecated sysctl (syscall) net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time - use net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time_ms instead
[   18.650396] usb 1-1.2: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[   18.730498] usb 1-1.2: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[   19.310948] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.310977] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.311036] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   59.050577] v3d fec00000.v3d: MMU error from client L2T (0) at 0x701000, pte invalid
[  292.921750] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  313.031230] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  313.193857] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=636b, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  313.193879] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[  313.193897] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB 2.0 Camera
[  313.193914] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
[  313.193931] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: SN0001
[  313.200715] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636b)
[  313.202201] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 10 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 1).
[  313.202885] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 14 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 1).
[  313.203129] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 16 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 1).
[  313.215821] input: USB 2.0 Camera: CyberTrack H4  as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/input/input1
[  313.223789] usb 1-1.2: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[  313.658255] usb 1-1.2: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[  313.668115] usb 1-1.2: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
```

I am following this article to create symbolic links for the device (both RPi camera and USB camera): https://g0kao.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/usb-port-assignment-on-a-raspberry-pi/ but since I can't find `USB` device, I can't do much.

I went ahead and used `productid:vendorid` = `0c45:636b` in the udev rules

`sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0c45", ATTRS{idProduct}=="636b", SYMLINK+="SIDECAMERA"
```

but it didn't help. In my code (I use opencv) where I need to give camera id,

`cv2.VideoCapture(0)` works but `cv2.VideoCapture("dev/SIDECAMERA")` doesn't.

**Related Problem**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951186/cant-find-ttyusbid

(Not sure if it helps but I am remotely accessing RPi using VNC)

Comment: Why do you expect the camera to show up as a serial device? I would expect it to show up as a video device.

Comment: I thought since camera is a USB camera, it might show the USB name. In case of video device, how will one define symbolic links? Details of the udev will still be same right?

Comment: `/dev/tty*` devices are serial devices (USB and otherwise). USB devices that aren't serial devices (cameras, keyboards, mice, soundcards, whatever) will not have `/dev/tty*` device names because they don't provide a serial interface. Cameras will typically be exposed as `/dev/video*` devices.

Comment: Thank you. That solved it.